# Creating increment limit

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Ok so I am making a like/dislike system for my website and I got it to work. The only problem is, is that a user can like something more than once, how do I stop this? heres my function

```
    function thumbup(uid, s) {
        const prevthumbs = s.thumbs

            firebase.db.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
                thumbs: prevthumbs + 1
            })
            
    }
```

How can I limit the increment to only one?

Answer (score 0):

To limit how often the user can do something, use their UID as the key for the operation.

For example, if you don't have too many users, you can have a field `likedBy` in the document which is an array of the UIDs of the users who liked this user.

It's a bit unclear how to exactly implement it in your code for me, as you're already writing to a `doc(uid)`, where usually the user is liking a post or something like that.

Comment: yeah so I added how many likes a user has on their profile, so im going into the that users doc and whenever someone clicks the thumbs up itll show the the likes on their profile. Unfortunately nested arrays arent supported into firebase so when i did this:
```
const peoplethatliked = [s.likedby, currentUser.uid]

firebase.db.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
    likedby: peoplethatliked 
   })
```
it didnt work. Is there possibly some way i could make this array work though?